# getting error while comapring reference number from two tables for login

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have two tables Resellers and Customers. Admin will add reseller fields and give reference number to the customer. Customer has to take that reference number and type while registering in the website. In the backend, that reference number written by the customer should match the reference number which he has provided. If it is same, then he can log in. Otherwise, he will see error message.

Here, I am not able to compare reference number. Value is not passing.

```
protected void SignInButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int customerID;

        Customer customer = new Customer();

        customer.CustomerName = CustomerNameTextBox.Text;
        customer.ShopName = ShopNameTextBox.Text;
        customer.Address = AddressTextBox.Text;
        customer.Mobile1 = Mobile1TextBox.Text;
        customer.Mobile2 = Mobile2TextBox.Text;
        customer.ReferenceNumber = ReferenceNumberTextBox.Text;
        customer.LoginID = Mobile1TextBox.Text;
        customer.Password = RandomNoGenerator.GenerateRandomNo();
        customer.SignUpDate = DateTime.Now;
        customer.Enabled = true;


        try
        {
            Reseller reseller = new Reseller();

            if (customer.ReferenceNumber == reseller.ReferenceNumber)
            {
                //MessageLabel.Text = "Customer successfully added";
                customerID = CustomerBL.AddCustomer(customer);
                MessageLabel.Text = "You've successfully signed up!";
                Response.Redirect("UserSignUpSuccess.aspx?CustomerID=" + customerID);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageLabel.Text = "Please Provide Same Reference Number";
            }
            //customerID = CustomerBL.AddCustomer(customer);
            //MessageLabel.Text = "You've successfully signed up!";
            //Response.Redirect("UserSignUpSuccess.aspx?CustomerID=" + customerID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageLabel.Text = "Some error occured while processing the request. Error Description <br/>" + ex.Message;
        }
```

Business Logic Layer Code

```
public class CustomerBL
{
    public static int AddCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        int customerID;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Customers] ([LoginID], [Password], [CustomerName], [ShopName], [Address], [Mobile1], [Mobile2], [ReferenceNumber], [SignUpDate], [Enabled]) " +
        "VALUES (@LoginID, @Password, @CustomerName, @ShopName, @Address, @Mobile1, @Mobile2, @ReferenceNumber, @SignUpDate, @Enabled); SELECT @@IDENTITY";

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginID", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.LoginID;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.Password;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.CustomerName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ShopName", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.ShopName;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.Address;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile1", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.Mobile1;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile2", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.Mobile2;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReferenceNumber", SqlDbType.Text).Value = customer.ReferenceNumber;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SignUpDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = customer.SignUpDate;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Enabled", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = customer.Enabled;

        customerID = DbUtility.UpdateDbGetIdentity(cmd);
        return customerID;
    }
```

Comment: It is not logical, you set `ReferenceNumber` to `customer`, then you want to compare `referenceNumber`s that you set to `customer`. That will always be true?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating `Reseller` instance but not initializing it before using it

```
Reseller reseller = new Reseller();

            if (customer.ReferenceNumber == reseller.ReferenceNumber)
            {
```

Assuming that the default constructor does not set-up `ReferenceNumber` for `Reseller` instance, you might want to initialize it before using it.